# Escrow check with past void date?

Tags: banking, check

I have an escrow check that is past 180 days.  It will be around 6 days past 180 come Monday. The check was issued by bank of america and my bank is chase.  Would they still let me deposit it or will another one have to be reissued?  How strict are banks with these things?  Would they tell me something like, too bad, your loss?  This is no small check.

Comment: @littleadv - Does it make a difference what kind of check it is sometimes?  This is no personal check, it is issued by bank of america regarding overpaying escrow.

Comment: is it a cashier's check?

Comment: @littleadv - how can i tell?

Comment: It usually says "Cashier's Check" in large letters on the top of the check.

Comment: Here's how a BOA cashier's check looks like: http://www.burbed.com/wp-content/uploads/2013/02/130216-investors-cashiers.jpg Cashier's checks do not go stale.

Comment: It looks very similar to that picture, but it does not say Cahsier's check at the top.  It has the amount and below that it says "VOID AFTER 180 DAYS". Next to the amount it says "Date 12/17/2013"

Comment: @if it doesn't say "cashier's check" then it is not cashier's check. For a regular check - your question is essentially identical to the one I linked to. Since checks go stale after 6 months, your case is kindof border-line and may fly more easily than others.

Comment: @littleadv - I guess all i can do is try at my local branch, right?  Do you normally go to the bank where you will deposit it or contact the bank that issued it?

Comment: I usually deposit checks through ATM or phone. The bank that will cause problems is the issuing bank anyway. If they decide not to honor a stale check - it will be bounced. But you won't know until you deposit. You can ask a replacement check, if the company that issued it is readily accessible, to be on the safe side. Or just deposit it and be done with it.